# Freya choppy in VirtualBox

Tags: release-freya, virtualbox

I am using latest VirtualBox to have elementary OS on my work PC for personal use. Work PC parameters: W7Pro, i7-4770k, 16GB RAM, 256 SSD, AMD FirePro V4900. I reserved 4 cores, 4GB RAM, 30GB SSD, 128MB 3D.

I do not know why, but elementary OS is very choppy. I tried Mint xfce on VBox too, but I haven't noticed any lag or choppiness. Maybe someone has any ideas what might be a problem?

elementary OS on VMWare Player works very well, but I would like to use VBox because of additional features.

Comment: Is Intel VT-x enabled in BIOS / UEFI settings